# Split single file to multiple "posts" in Hugo?

Tags: hugo

Hugo's one-file->one-page model is nice and simple, especially for a blog.  But sometimes you want to write an "article" for a blog and split it into 2 or more pieces for separate pages (perhaps to be posted on separate days, or whatever).

Is there a way to do this within Hugo?  Perhaps a combination of something you put in a layout/theme/shortcode and internal markup within the page (to signal where to split the article)?

Possible models might include:

- 1 input post "splits" into 2/3/4 posts when the site is built to `public`
- 1 input post is duplicated into 2/3/4 posts when the site is built to `public` but somehow each duplicate isn't an *exact* duplicate but instead has the whole post but certain parts of the post are hidden/invisible, via CSS, such that they represent the 2/3/4 "pages" of the post.

Or, is this something you do external to Hugo?

**UPDATE:** I can see I need to clarify this.  Consider this [random illustrative blog post](https://kubasejdak.com/techniques-of-variadic-templates) - it is the third of three closely related posts, and even has a set of links at the top so you can find the earlier posts in the series.  Lots of technical blogs do this sort of thing (at least the ones I read).

Now, I'm not looking for a CMS or anything complex.  What I do now with Hugo is `hugo new posts/an-article-about-constexpr.md` and I write one markdown file and it becomes one "post" in standard Hugo fashion.  Exactly what you want a SSG to do.

What I *want* to do is write one markdown file but have some kind of markup in it separating it into sections (like `<!-- More -->` on steroids) so that instead of generating one page of my site it generates three (in this example) - three separate articles with links from the main page in the "posts" section, etc. etc.  And for bonus points, I'd like to generate these "table of contents" sections with links to each of the pages.

So I've been doing that with a cobbled-up awk script that generates pages right next to the post, in the posts directory.  I set the post to draft so it doesn't get published, but the pages generated by the awk script have draft=false so they *do* get published.  And the dates get set so they're "in order".

And that's working, but before I invest more time in my little script, I wanted to see if there was a *proper* way to do this *within* hugo.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to consider storing the posts as structured data and using [Data Templates](https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/).

Comment: To me, that seems like three separate posts, and maybe another post that serves as a summary with the links to the others. The table of contents could be viewed as a sub-menu in that case. In Hugo, using a page bundle would be one way to handle it. But I think, as you realize, a CMS would give you tools to do what you're describing -- maintain data across items/entities. I wouldn't expect Hugo to natively work that same way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by one-file->one-page model.
I have very few parts of any hugo site which one markdown file=one rendered html page.

Could just be the way I build, but everything I've done so far has been vanilla hugo.

To answer your question: Yes, you are correct that would work. There a few ways to do this (I list one below), but maybe a deeper look would be separating the concept of a "tool-chain" and what Hugo is in that tool chain, from a CMS, which Hugo is not.

So, to possibly answer your specific question though:

1. You can store content in markdown, markdown front matter, or a Data form (XML/JSON) in hugo. Using the page resources {{ .GetPage }} you can access any content and load it in any template or using shortcodes, load it in other markdown.
2. If I needed to do this as part of a tool chain, i.e. use specific markdown and re-use it in multiple places, I would create a front matter variable, or taxonomy or tag depending on what groupings I needed where, so this was scalable. params such as
   "articleAuthor: Jessie P."
   "date: DATE HERE"
   "tags: etc. etc."

Then lets say I know that's going to be a blog, well fine, then it will be in the corresponding content folder, but if I needed all of Jessie's articles, or articles on that date, or that specific article, I would use the shortcode I make or directly in a template, using .GetPage Match - import the markdown pages I need based on the parameters I need.

But on the other hand, I would need to understand the problem being solved, but, here are a few hugo docs to help you out:

https://gohugo.io/functions/getpage/#readout
https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-bundles/

Remember, Hugo is not a CMS, it is a site generator. If you want a CMS, you can always use Wordpress headless, or any other solution out there.

(off the top of my head using page bundles)

```
{{ $headlessBundle := .Site.GetPage "/blogs/specific-blog/index" }}   
{{ with $getContent := $headlessBundle.Resources.Match "intro.md" }}  
{{ (index $getContent 0).Content }}
```

(You would use various "Where" statements to "filter" content based on the params or however you delineate what you want).

Or for instance if I wanted only the text that had an H1 tag:

```
{{ $.Scratch.Set "summary" ((delimit (findRE "(<h1.*?>.*?</h1>\\s*)+"    .Content) "[&hellip;]") | plainify | replaceRE "&amp;" "&" | safeHTML) }}
{{ $.Scratch.Get "summary" }}
```

Based on the update to the question:
https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/split-markdown-content-in-two-files-but-dont-render-shortcodes-as-raw-text/32080/2
https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/getting-a-list-from-within-a-shortcode/28126
https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/splitting-content-into-sections-based-on-header-level/33749
https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/multiple-content-blocks-on-a-single-page/9092/3

jrmooring answered it best in the above with clear examples and code.

Though, note: If I was doing this in a technical blog this would be integrated into the CMS and coordinated with the builder.

Comment: I've added a clarification, with an example, to what I'm asking for.  I think I wrote it initially badly because your  interesting suggestions seem more for taking fragments of content and using them in multiple places.  I'm more interested in taking a big article in one file (where it is convenient for me to see the whole thing) but have it published into three separate articles, part1, part2, and part3.  For example.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overlook the simplest possible solution:

Manually write the numbered list linking to all posts in the series. Manually insert that text at the top of each of the posts.

This has the advantage that it takes a few minutes to implement without needing anything non-vanilla or complex.

The disadvantage is obviously that it won't automatically update when you add new posts to the series. You'll have to update the text at the head of each post.

Comment: TY, though I haven't overlooked it.  This is what I _do_ do.  And it has exactly the advantage and disadvantage you mention!